# How to make real http calls in angular unit tests

Tags: angularjs

I am writing unit tests in angular js using karma. I have to mock http requests for these tests. Is there any method to make real http calls so that I can work on server response?

Comment: I have gone through several documents to unit test angular js services, but all of them refers to do a mock service test. even in the angular website itself.

Comment: Mock test will never make a web service call. They are purely client side testing only

Comment: Yes you are right. Actually problem in mocking http request is that if server is changed in future then these tests will be useless until i change mock response according to server change.

Comment: Yes it makes sense but I can't find solution of my problem. What if server code changes?

Comment: Unit test are ment to written after development finishes only. No code changes are expected after that

Comment: That's not the responsibility of a unit test, but more of integration tests

Comment: @Nitheesh You should definitely write unit tests *during* development

Comment: anyone figure this out? I've already had a problem where the server changed and I was not informed, so the mock data remained the same. I had no idea the app was failing because it's not testing the real data.